# Laravel: How to define this relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've been confused by this all day.
So I have three models: `Agent`, `Customer`, and `User`.

`Agent` is a `User`.

`Customer` is also a `User` but belongs to an `Agent`.

`User` can be an `Agent` or a `Customer`.

Now I want to know the Eloquent relationships of these three models. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i can think of is to use Many to Many polymorphic relationship.

Since User can be both an agent and a customer we will create the users table and create another table then we name it userable table which will help map users to either agent, customer or both.

the userable table will have these fields

```
user_id - integer
userable_id - integer
userable_type - string
```

The user_id will hold the user id,the userable_id will hold either agent or customer id and the userable_type holds the Agent or Custmoer Model Class name

User's Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    public function agents()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Agent', 'userable');
    }


    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Customer', 'userable');
    }
}
```

Agent Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Agent extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'userable');
    }
}
```

Customer Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'userable');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be "cleaner" if `User` is an (abstract) class, and both `Agent` and `Customer` extend `User`? Then you would have two sorts of accounts. You would then have a One-To-Many Relationship between the `Agent` and the `Customer` (alternatively a Many-To-Many Relationship, if a `Customer` can have more than one `Agent`).

The downside would be, that you wouldn't have just one list but two and an `Agent` can't just become a `Customer`, but the connections are more clear and are on the database level and you don't have to check the relationships on the app level (e.g. what happens when a `Customer` who has an `Agent` becomes an `Agent`, is there then an `Agent`->`Agent` relationship?).

Then you can also have an easier time adding extra fields to the `Agent` or `Customer` without one affecting the other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't/shouldn't have 3 models, but one abstract class `User` and 2 derived classes `Agent` and `Customer`. Then your relationships are pretty straight forward:

```php
// Agent extends User
public function customers() 
{
  return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'agent_id');
}

// Customer extends User
public function agent()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Agent::class, 'agent_id');
}
```